# VBA create several textboxes/comboboxes dynamically in userform

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, combobox

I create dynamically a Userform with comboboxes and textboxes. one of each per row. The user will choose how many lines he wants.
So far I can adjust the size of the Userform according to the number of rows and create the first row. But an error occurred for the second row:
Run-time error '-2147221005(800401f3)': Invalid Class String
The result is [Userform generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLfUd.jpg)
Here is my code. to simplify I allocated the row variable to Nb=3

```
    Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim Nb As Integer 'Nb = number of people to record
    Dim UF2 As Object
    Dim TbHour, TbBin As msforms.TextBox 'txtbox for number of hours done and bins
    Dim CBName As msforms.ComboBox 'List with names
    Dim i 'i = loop to create rows

    Nb = 3

    Set UF2 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
        With UF2
        .Properties("Caption") = "Packing record"
        .Properties("Width") = "250"
        .Properties("Height") = "50"
        .Properties("Height") = .Properties("Height") * Nb + 10
        End With

    For i = 1 To Nb
        Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.combobox." & i) **'here is where the error happens on the second For/Next loop**
            With CBName
            .Name = "Combobox" & i
            .Top = 0
            .Top = .Top * i + 10
            .Left = 10
            .Width = 100
            .Height = 20
            End With

            With UF2.CodeModule
                .InsertLines 1, "Public sub userform_initialize()"
                .InsertLines 2, "Me.ComboBox1.AddItem (""1"")"
                .InsertLines 3, "End sub"
            End With

        Set TbHour = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.textbox." & i)
            With TbHour
            .Top = 0
            .Top = .Top * i + 10
            .Left = 120
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 20
            End With

    Next i

    i = i + 1
Set TbBin = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.textbox." & i)
        With TbBin
        .Top = 10
        .Top = .Top * i
        .Left = 180
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 20
        End With


    VBA.UserForms.Add(UF2.Name).Show
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove UF2


    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just declare a `New ComboBox` variable, and `.Add` that object?

Comment: How do you write this? So far I always used 'controls.add("forms.xxxx.1")'

Comment: In simplified terms that fit a comment... `Me.Controls.Add(New ComboBox)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in `.Name = "Combobox" & i`

I suspect it's due to "Combobox1" being the *default* name of any newly inserted combobox control so that:

- after first iteration you have a combobox *you* named after "Combobox1"
- at the 2nd iteration the `Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")` statement is trying to generate a combobox whose name, before any subsequent explicit `Name` property assignment, defaults to "Combobox1" which, however, is already the name you assigned to the first combobox. hence the "Ambiguous Name" error

So there are three ways you can avoid the "Ambiguous Name" error:

- change `.Name = "Combobox" & i` to `.Name = "ComboBox" & i`

  where the case difference is enough to avoid conflicting with the *default* name
- omit that statement altogether

  and have VBA name it for you "ComboBox1", "ComboBox2", ...
- use `Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", Name:="Combobox" & i)`

  i.e. you assign the `Name` right at combobox instantiation

Other than that, your code would hit the "userform_initialize" code writing issue since it would write as many subs as comboboxes to add

To face all what above issues and do some refactoring, your code could be as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim nb As Integer 'Nb = number of people to record
    Dim UF2 As Object ' or use 'As VBComponent'
    Dim i 'i = loop to create rows

    nb = 3
    Set UF2 = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    With UF2
        .Properties("Caption") = "Packing record"
        .Properties("Width") = "250"
        .Properties("Height") = "50"
        .Properties("Height") = .Properties("Height") * nb + 10

        .CodeModule.InsertLines 2, "Public sub userform_initialize()" '<--| start writing your "UserForm_Initialize" sub code
        For i = 1 To nb
            With .Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", Name:="Combobox" & i) ' or simply: With .Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
                .top = 20 * (i - 1) + 5
                .Left = 10
                .Width = 100
                .Height = 20
            End With

            .CodeModule.InsertLines 2 + i, "Me.ComboBox" & i & ".AddItem (""1"")" '<--| keep adding lines to your "UserForm_Initialize" sub code

            With .Designer.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1")
                .top = 0
                .top = 20 * (i - 1) + 5
                .Left = 120
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 20
            End With
        Next i
        .CodeModule.InsertLines 2 + i, "End sub" '<--| finish writing your "UserForm_Initialize" sub code

        i = i - 1
        With .Designer.Controls.Add("forms.textbox.1")
            .top = 20 * (i - 1) + 5
            .Left = 180
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 20
        End With


        VBA.UserForms.Add(.Name).Show
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove UF2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! I don't know why I tried something more complicated than needed to be

Answer (score 1):

`Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.combobox." & i)`

The class String is ALWAYS Forms.ComboBox.1 - never .2 or .3

Therefore do:

`Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")`

Comment: That is what I thought but I have an error "Run-time: Ambiguous Name" on the same code line

Comment: Yeh sorry I didnt spend a lot of time on this. user<numbers> gave you the idea to use the naming at creatin time: Set CBName = UF2.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "Combo" & i)