# adding multiple labels and textboxes to an Excel userform during runtime using vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm creating an inventory management tool with Excel VBA. I've created code that gathers a list of names from a drop down box on Internet Explorer and puts them into an array.

[image]

What I need to do is something similar to [vba create several textboxes comboboxes dynamically in userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945089/vba-create-several-textboxes-comboboxes-dynamically-in-userform), but I would be dynamically adding labels for the user names and textboxes for the number of FLNs each person would be receiving.  These would then go into a predefined userform I've already created.

[image]

Per the code example above, I realize I can't use `.Name = "Textbox" & i` to rename the next label or textbox. `i` has to equal to an ever-changing list, so it can't be set in stone; hence why there has to be as many labels and textboxes as `UBound(UserArray)`.

**UPDATED**

```
Private Sub CreateControl()
    Dim newTxt As msforms.Control, newLbl
    Dim i As Integer, TopAmt
    Dim UserArray As String

    TopAmt = 30

    For i = LBound(MyArray) + 1 To UBound(MyArray) - 1
        Set newLbl = MultipleOptionForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With newLbl
            .Name = "Label" & i
            .Left = 10
            .Top = TopAmt
            .WordWrap = False
            .AutoSize = True
            .Visible = True
            .Caption = MyArray(i)
            Debug.Print .Name,
        End With

        Set newTxt = MultipleOptionForm.Controls.Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.Textbox.1", Name:="Textbox" & i)
        With newTxt
            .Left = 150
            .Top = TopAmt
            .Visible = True
            .Width = 20
            Debug.Print .Name
        End With
        TopAmt = TopAmt + newTxt.Height
    Next

    MultipleOptionForm.Show
End Sub
```

[image: Any suggestions on how to do this, if possible? I'd hate to use the Excel spreadsheet itself to accomplish this.]

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem with using `i` is

Comment: The approved answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945089/vba-create-several-textboxes-comboboxes-dynamically-in-userform explains it better than I can. From what I gathered, `Combobox1` is a default name for the control, so I can't use `"Combobox" & i` to name it. They suggested that `"ComboBox" & i` would work. That's not the bulk of my question. My question is how to dynamically add labels and textboxes to a predefined form. I thought putting the code for one each in a `for...next` loop would work, but it leaves the form blank, for some reason.

Comment: You can rename the controls unless another control has it's name.

Comment: Instead of worrying about the controls names, it would probably be easier to create two class level collections and add the controls to the collection as they are created.

Comment: In that case all you need to do is not use the default "base" name of "Textbox" and just use (eg) "txtBox"   Then there's no chance of names colliding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lou the answer to the question is misleading.  The question wants to provide a default name when adding the control by changing its ProgID ( bstrProgID is a string that references the class that is to be created).

You can rename the new controls provided that another control does not have the same name.

You can also pass the controls name as an argument to the `Controls.Add` method.

Your labels are not showing is that you never set the `Label.Caption` value.

[image]

```
Private Sub CreateControl()
    Dim newLbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim newTxt As MSForms.Control
    Dim i As Integer, TopAmt
    Dim UserArray As Variant

    TopAmt = 50
    UserArray = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Gorrilla")

    For i = LBound(UserArray) To UBound(UserArray)
        Set newLbl = MultipleOptionForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With newLbl
            .Name = "Label" & i
            .Left = 50
            .Top = TopAmt
            .Visible = True
            .Caption = UserArray(i)
            Debug.Print .Name,
        End With

        Set newTxt = MultipleOptionForm.Controls.Add(bstrProgID:="Forms.Textbox.1", Name:="Textbox" & i)
        With newTxt
            .Left = 100
            .Top = TopAmt
            .Visible = True
            Debug.Print .Name
        End With
        TopAmt = TopAmt + newTxt.Height
    Next
End Sub
```

---

### Next Issue: how do you get the data from these dynamically created textboxes?

```
Dim newTxt As MSForms.Control
For i = LBound(UserArray) To UBound(UserArray)
    set newTxt  =  MultipleOptionForm.Controls("Textbox" & i)
    If UserArray(i) <> newTxt.Value then
        'Do something
    End if
Next
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Had to make a few modifications as everything was mushed together in my userform, but it works our perfectly. Updating my original code to show the results. Thanks.

Comment: Next issue...how do you get the data from these dynamically created textboxes? I tried using `MultipleOptionForm.Textbox1.Value`, but it's not allowing me to view it in a `MsgBox`.

Comment: I appended the anser to your "Next Issue" to my answer.

Comment: I just tried that and I'm still not getting the `MsgBox` to show. I even checked the button name (`AsgnFLNButton`) and the procedure that handles the click (`Sub AsgnFLNButton_Click()`). Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I should be able to get the value of the textbox, but it's like the form pops up and prevents the button click event to occur.

Comment: I'm still at a loss. If I make a function to accept the button click within the bulk of my code, the form does nothing. If I attach the function to the actual button itself, then I get an out of range error because there's nothing feeding the function from the bulk of the code. I even tried `UserArray = Module1.VERIFY_MULTIPLE.UserArray` and still get an error. Any ideas, or do I have to ask a separate question?

Comment: A separate question would be best.  It's too hard to explain things in comments.