# retrieving data from multiple textboxes created during runtime in an Excel userform using vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Okay...so I got some great help resolving my issue with [adding multiple labels and textboxes to an Excel userform during runtime using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078348/adding-multiple-labels-and-textboxes-to-an-excel-userform-during-runtime-using-v/46079555?noredirect=1#comment79162245_46079555). Now, the issue is I'm trying to retrieve data from those dynamically created textboxes. It's not that I can't get the data, it's that I can't pull it out of the form and use it once the form is closed.

I used the following code sets for retrieving data from a single option textbox and it works perfectly:

```
Private Sub SOSubmitButton_Click()
    FLNAmt = SingleOptionForm.SOBox
    Unload SingleOptionForm
End Sub
```

and

```
SingleOptionForm.Show
SingleOptionForm.Hide
```

When I use `FLNAmt` shortly after hiding the form, there's data in the variable. However, using some of the much similar coding:

```
Private Sub AsgnFLNButton_Click()
    Dim MultFLNAmt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    If i = 1 Then
        MultFLNAmt = MultipleOptionForm.Controls("Textbox" & i)
    Else
        MultFLNAmt = MultFLNAmt & "," & MultipleOptionForm.Controls("Textbox" & i)
    End If

    Unload MultipleOptionForm
End Sub
```

and

```
MultipleOptionForm.Show    
MultipleOptionForm.Hide

MsgBox MultFLNAmt
```

When the `MsgBox` appears, MultFLNAmt is blank. Is there something different I need to do when gathering data from dynamically created textboxes and using it after the form closes than I do when using a textbox already hard coded into the form?

Comment: If you `unload` a form, an dynamically created fields are lost. I think that's the case with hiding the form as well (you might have to investigate that one). You could always capture the values before you unload/hide the form. Or if you are feeling really adventurous, you could have `with events` for the dynamically created fields and load the data there, which you can then call at a later time (there are a lot of examples for this on the net)

Comment: MultFLNAmt is a local variable, so it goes out of scope. try putting option explicit on

Comment: @Zac Do you have one example in particular I could reference to? I've been doing a lot of searching and feel I may not be wording what I'm looking for correctly. Could setting the dynamic data to an environment variable I can use later work?

Comment: @Phil `FLNAmt` is also a local variable, but, like I said, I can use the data from there, but I can't use the data from `MultFLNAmt`. In my opinion, both codings should work.

Comment: no, FLNAmt is not declared, so it's scope is not local.  Put option explicit at the top of your code and see what doesn't compile

Comment: I'm confused. I "can" use the data from `FLNAmt` after the form is closed. I "cannot" use the data from `MultFLNAmt`. I'm sure `FLNAmt` will not compile once I add `Option Explicit`. Neither variable are declared. I agree that I should, but the point is that `FLNAmt` holds data from a static `Textbox` and I can use it once the form is unloaded. What I'm trying to do is the same thing with `MultFLNAmt`, which holds data from a dynamic `Textbox`.

Comment: FLNAmt is not declared so (probably) has a global scope. if you remove 'Dim MultFLNAmt As String' then it will have similar behaviour

Comment: Your `MultFLNAmt` variable is declared in `AsgnFLNButton_Click` sub so it only holds the value for the life of that sub. As you haven't declared `FLNAmt` variable, it's acting as a (private) global variable. I would suggest if you want to hold the value from `MultFLNAmt` variable, assign it to a global variable and then you will have access to it

Comment: Same as what @Phil said :)

Comment: WOW!! I didn't even catch that one. Thanks guys!

Comment: We've all been there mate .. it's always the smallest things that you miss :)