# combobox addItem strangely not working - remains blank

Tags: vba, excel

very simple Problem:

```
Dim myForm As Object
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
Set MyComboBox = myForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
With MyComboBox
    .Left = 100
    .Top = 20 + x * 10
    .Height = 16
    .Width = 100

     For Each col In fields
        .AddItem col
     Next
 End With
```

I can clearly print out the values in fields (which is a variant), but somehow the Combobox remains blank... Any ideas? I'm wasting way to much time on this...
thanks for your help

Comment: Where are you defining `fields`?

Comment: Did you try adding a literal string and check if you can see it?

Comment: it is an Input of the Sub - "fields As Variant". which is a return value of a function (private function x() as variant) @braX

Comment: @TomSchardt I tried and I don't see it... what is happening? :O

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the additem line and see if it stops there at all. I wouldnt recommend using a `Variant` for this, but you may have your reasons. You can also try `.AddItem CStr(col)`

Comment: If I set .ListIndex = 0 I can see the first entry, but the Dropdown still is blank...

Comment: @braX breakpoint working as expected, CStr() didn't do the trick

Comment: How about a `Debug.Print col` to see if the values show up in the debug window?

Comment: @braX they Show up as expected.

Comment: How about creating the combobox at design time instead of run time? Why do you need to create it programmatically?

Comment: FYI: the form is displayed in the end with: VBA.UserForms.Add(myForm.Name).Show

Comment: @braX because depending on the Input of the user, the fields are different

Comment: The fields are different, but the combobox itself isn't.

Comment: ah sorry I misread - I Need a dynamic number of comboboxes... don't ask why ;) Never thought I failed at filling them though

Comment: this line: `VBA.UserForms.Add(myForm.Name).Show` looks to me like you are creating a second form, and showing that instead of the form that you are adding values to. (Just a guess, probably my last one) Can you not just simply use `myForm.Show` ?

Comment: @braX tried, but not working - the usual "this function not supported..blabla"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA create several textboxes/comboboxes dynamically in userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945089/vba-create-several-textboxes-comboboxes-dynamically-in-userform)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945089/vba-create-several-textboxes-comboboxes-dynamically-in-userform - this solves the Problem... what a hassle VBA can be